# Print fully loaded (!) website as PDF with Chrome in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, javascript

I want to print a PDF of a website with folium maps on it.
A great example can be seen at https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html , but other Jupyter Notebooks can serve well as an example, too.
In addition, I want to do this in an automated way, e.g. as a batch script.
For this I have been working with the command below

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="/my/path/to/output.pdf" --delay=15000 --disable-gpu --print-background --enable-logging --v=1 "https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html"
```

Somehow not all maps are fully loaded in the resulting PDF.
I tried to increase the delay but even after 45 seconds some tiles were missing.
This is not an issue with my internet connection - when looking at it in the browser, the tiles are displayed after a shorter time period.

Which parameters do I need to add or alter in order to get the PDF?

Comment: By the way, I first reported this as a bug but at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=986740#c3 they claimed it should be rather some additional parameters I need to pass in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some times ago.

This command can help you:

```
 --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw
```

This should solve the problem

Comment: Could you explain what this command does?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that command! Sadly I cannot see any effect of it so it might be only part of a solution